# Rearrange list to satisfy a condition

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this during a coding interview but wasn't able to solve this. Any pointers would be very helpful.

I was given an integer list (think of it as a number line) which needs to be rearranged so that the difference between elements is equal to `M` (an integer which is given). The list needs to be rearranged in such a way that the value of the `max absolute difference between the elements' new positions and the original positions` needs to be minimized. Eventually, this value multiplied by 2 is returned.

Test cases:

```
//1.
original_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
M = 2
rearranged_list = [-0.5, 1.5, 3.5, 5.5]
// difference in values of original and rearranged lists
diff = [1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5]
max_of_diff = 1.5 // list is rearranged in such a way so that this value is minimized
return_val = 1.5 * 2 = 3 

//2. 
original_list = [1, 2, 4, 3]
M = 2
rearranged_list = [-1, 1, 3, 5]
// difference in values of original and rearranged lists
diff = [2, 1, 1, 2]
max_of_diff = 2 // list is rearranged in such a way so that this value is minimized
return_val = 2 * 2 = 4 

Constraints:
1 <= list_length <= 10^5
1 <= M <= 10^4
-10^9 <= list[i] <= 10^9
```

There's a question on leetcode which is very similar to this: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimize-deviation-in-array/ but there, the operations that are performed on the array are mentioned while that's not been mentioned here. I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can think of it:

The "rearanged" list is like a straight line that has a slope that corresponds to M.

Here is a visualisation for the first example:

[image]

The black dots are the input values [1, 2, 3, 4] where the index of the array is the X-coordinate, and the actual value at that index, the Y-coordinate.

The green line is determined by M. Initially this line runs through the origin at (0, 0). The red line segments represent the differences that must be taken into account.

Now the green line has to move vertically to its optimal position. We can see that we only need to look at the difference it makes with the first and with the last point. The other two inputs will never contribute to an extreme. This is generally true: there are only two input elements that need to be taken into account. They are the points that make the greatest (signed -- not absolute) difference and the least difference.

We can see that we need to move the green line in such a way that the signed differences with these two extremes are each others opposite: i.e. their absolute difference becomes the same, but the sign will be opposite.

Twice this absolute difference is what we need to return, and it is actually the difference between the greatest (signed) difference and the least (signed) difference.

So, in conclusion, we must generate the values on the green line, find the least and greatest (signed) difference with the data points (Y-coordinates) and return the difference between those two.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript running the two examples you provided:

```js
function solve(y, slope) {
    let low = Infinity;
    let high = -Infinity;
    for (let x = 0; x < y.length; x++) {
        let dy = y[x] - x * slope;
        low = Math.min(low, dy);
        high = Math.max(high, dy);
    }
    return high - low;
}

console.log(solve([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)); // 3
console.log(solve([1, 2, 4, 3], 2)); // 4
```

Comment: Great answer, upvoted! Would accept this as an answer after I understand this in depth. How did you go about solving this? Is there a similar question with the same pattern? And an unrelated question - how do I get good at solving questions like these that I've never seen before? Is there a trick? I always seem to get lost when I encounter questions that don't follow famous algorithms. Would blindly practicing more problems help?

Comment: I am no expert in the area of *learning*, as to what are the best methods... but I have 40 years of experience with coding, so I guess it helps to develop an intuition of some sorts.

Comment: A couple of questions - would be great if you could answer them: 1. how is the difference between greatest (signed) difference and the least (signed) difference perfectly equal to twice the absolute difference of points in original and redrawn green line? Is that just a coincidence or are these somehow related? 2. The question also asks to minimize the absolute difference. Don't see you doing that in code but your code still returns the min difference. How is that?

Comment: (1) Imagine what happens when you move the green line up one unit: the point where the maximum signed difference occurs, will see that difference reduce with 1 unit, while the point where the minimum signed difference occurs, will see that difference increase with 1 unit. So the difference between these signed differences (`high` and `low`) is not influenced by moving the green line up and down. When the green line is at is optimal position, then `high == -low`, and thus `2*abs(high)` (the answer) is same as `high - low` (just subsitute).

Comment: I think that last part also answers to point 2.

Comment: Much clearer now. Thank you so much. Had not understood that the difference between high and low remains the same no matter how much the line is moved vertically. So this also means we don't really need to minimize this value. Understood that now.

Comment: Great. I reread my previous comment, and see I have some inaccuracies in it, but the important thing is that you got it. ;-)

Comment: Right. Had to draw the graphs using pen and paper to understand. What part of the problem made you understand that this problem could be solved using this method? Would never have imagined that this problem could be solved this way.

Comment: One thing that helps, is to find a way to visualise a problem. We humans are much better at solving problems when we see it happening before our eyes. Like I wrote, things eventually bubble up from your unconscious mind if there is enough experience to draw on... intuition.